# How to write a query joining multiple tables that returns a result set with null for columns

Tags: mysql, sql

If i have these tables

```
address         quarter         
------------  ----------
address_id     quarter_id
quarter_id     quarter_name
address_name   quarter_code
```

If the user provides the address information (address_name) the quarter will be identified because the address is within a quarter. But if the user doesn't provide an address but a quarter the address information will not be available.

```
Select      address.address_name, 
            quarter.quarter_code 
From        address 
some_join   quarter on  address.quarter_id = quarter.quarter_id 
where       address.address_name like @param 
or          quarter.quarter_code = @param
```

I want a result like this if the where clause matches on the address_name condition.

```
address_name  | quarter_code
stress eight     14400459
```

But if the user types 14400459

```
address_name  | quarter_code
null            14400459
```

I had difficult to formulate this question. It's been a long time since I saw sql joins and this kind of thing get out of mind so easily.

Comment: which rdbms ???

Comment: where is address_code in table ??

Comment: I corrected the question. I'm using MySql.

Comment: still you need to tag rdbms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right join can be tricky; here is how it should be constructed, plus you want the first non-null value to match the parameter:

```
select *
from address as a
right join quarter as q
on q.quarter_id = a.quarter_id
and coalesce(a.address_name, q.quarter_code) = @param
```

Or better yet:

```
select *
from address as a
right join quarter as q
on q.quarter_id = a.quarter_id
and (
    a.address_name = @param
    or
    q.quarter_code = @param
    )
```